# Axes3d vs axes3d matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I just finished a horrible install of scipy, numpy, and matplotlib on OSX Lion. For some reason, I can't do a:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3d
```

Error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3dPlot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3d
ImportError: cannot import name Axes3d
```

but I can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
```

Is there a  different between Axes3d and axes3d, or is my file just named with a lowercase 'a' for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following two things work for me (watch your capitalization):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
```

But I get the same error for what you wrote (with the d in 3d in lower case). Note that the two imports that do work are not equivalent.

Comment: Here's a place to install it, https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/?source=typ_redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Please use above command to use the 3D image for an object